# How to best parallelize code modifying several slices of the same Rust vector?

Tags: rust, parallel-processing, borrow-checker, unsafe, rayon

Let's say we want to double (in-place) each element in each of the slices of a vector, where the slices are defined by a list of pairs - (start, end) positions. The following code expresses the intent idiomatically, but doesn't compile because of the mutable borrow of the vector inside the parallel `for_each`:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    let slice_pairs = vec![(0, 3), (4, 7), (8, 10)];

    slice_pairs.into_par_iter().for_each(|(start, end)| {
        let slice = &mut data[start..end];
        for elem in slice.iter_mut() {
            *elem *= 2;
        }
    });

    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

There is a real potential for data races here - to rule them out, you need to check if the slices overlap. The question is what's the best way to do this in Rust, either thru unsafe code or a safe API. The following code uses `unsafe` to "go ahead and do this"; my question is if there's a better way than the below (which transmutes the vector's base pointer to an i64 and back to "blind" the borrow checker to the problem.)

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    let slice_pairs = vec![(0, 4), (4, 7), (7, 10)];

    let ptr_outer = data.as_mut_ptr();
    let ptr_int : i64 = unsafe { mem::transmute(ptr_outer) };

    slice_pairs.into_par_iter().for_each(|(start, end)| {
        unsafe {
            let ptr : *mut i32 = mem::transmute(ptr_int);
            let slice = std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr.add(start), end - start);

            for elem in slice.iter_mut() {
                *elem *= 2;
            }
        }
    });

    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

Comment: In case of doubling, there's another way to consider, but O(N) in memory - allocate a vector of atomic integers with initialization of 1 (those will be multipliers to the actual data), process ranges in parallel, multiply atomics (they provide sync). Then run parallel multiplication of actual data by multipliers over chunks (not overlapping, thus no sync required)

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov No need to allocate and copy, there is [`AtomicX::from_mut_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicI32.html#method.from_mut_slice) (on nightly, on stable you can use unsafe code).

Comment: I've edited my answer to add an unchecked (and unsafe) version of `split_many()` which can be used if the regions are known not to overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split_at_mut()` to break up the slice into multiple slices using safe code:

```rust
fn split_many<'a, T>(mut slice: &'a mut [T], regions: &[(usize, usize)]) -> Vec<&'a mut [T]> {
    let mut regions = regions.to_vec();
    regions.sort_by_key(|&(b, _e)| b);
    let mut ret = vec![];
    let mut offset = 0;
    for (b, e) in regions {
        assert!(b >= offset && e >= b); // prohibit overlaps
        let (chosen, rest) = slice.split_at_mut(e - offset);
        ret.push(&mut chosen[b - offset..]);
        offset = e;
        slice = rest;
    }
    ret
}
```

With that helper in place, you can express parallel in-place manipulation in the "obvious" way:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    let slice_pairs = vec![(0, 3), (4, 7), (8, 10)];

    split_many(&mut data, &slice_pairs)
        .into_par_iter()
        .for_each(|region| {
            for elem in region.iter_mut() {
                *elem *= 2;
            }
        });

    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8c7fa8b62ef41c4137979584eebe993b)

Note that as long as the regions are represented by arbitrary indices supplied at run-time, it's necessary to make an initial pass through them to ensure they don't overlap (`split_many()` panics if it detects overlap). Failing to do so would be *unsound*, as simply choosing overlapping regions would cause undefined behavior. However, if you control the code that generates the regions and know that they don't overlap, you could make a faster unsafe version of `split_many()`. Relying on external guarantees, it doesn't need to either sort or allocate a new set of regions, and can even return a `ParallelIterator` directly:

```
/// Split `slice` into `regions` and iterate over them in parallel.
/// Safety: regions must not overlap.
unsafe fn split_many_unchecked<'a, T: Send + Sync>(
    slice: &'a mut [T],
    regions: &'a [(usize, usize)],
) -> impl ParallelIterator<Item = &'a mut [T]> + 'a {
    struct Wrap<T>(*mut T);
    unsafe impl<T> Sync for Wrap<T> {}
    unsafe impl<T> Send for Wrap<T> {}
    let slice = Wrap(slice.as_mut_ptr());
    regions.par_iter().map(move |&(b, e)| {
        let _ = &slice; // prevent closure from capturing slice.0
        std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(slice.0.add(b), e - b)
    })
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f280873b2b1e75bcd5ef69693e9cb760)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest transforming `slice_pairs` into a sequence of mutable slices first, then use all these slices in parallel.

Subdividing a whole slice into multiple independent sub-slices (from the borrow-checker's point of view) can be done with [`slice::split_at_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut).
Of course, the indices in `slice_pairs` must be ordered and must not overlap, for these sub-slices to be correct.

Note that I tried to use `.map().collect()`, instead of an explicit loop with `.push()`, in order to build the sequence of slices, but I failed...
The compiler said that the `FnMut` closure in `.map()` could not return a reference; may be someone could fix my code...

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    let slice_pairs = vec![(0, 3), (4, 7), (8, 10)];

    // build a sequence of mutable slices
    let mut slices = Vec::with_capacity(slice_pairs.len());
    let mut remaining = data.as_mut_slice();
    let mut idx = 0;
    for (start, end) in slice_pairs {
        let (_skip, tail) = remaining.split_at_mut(start - idx);
        let (sl, tail) = tail.split_at_mut(end - start);
        remaining = tail;
        idx = end;
        slices.push(sl);
    }
    println!("slices: {:?}", slices);

    // parallel usage of the mutable slices
    slices.into_par_iter().for_each(|sl| {
        for elem in sl.iter_mut() {
            *elem *= 2;
        }
    });

    println!("data: {:?}", data);
}
/*
slices: [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [9, 10]]
data: [2, 4, 6, 4, 10, 12, 14, 8, 18, 20]
*/
```

Comment: I guess `split_at_mut` or something similar is the way to go, and I guess there's no `split_according_to_a_list_of_pairs_mut` nor an iterator in Rayon that "just does this." Thanks!

Comment: @YossiKreinin You can definitely write a `split_according_to_a_list_of_pairs_mut()` in safe Rust using `split_at_mut()` as a building-block, though. See `split_many()` in the solution I wrote before I realized prog-fh beat me to the punch: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2c0c42d79b2f44bebde6ed312cc4e8ea

Comment: @user4815162342 thanks, this looks good and I guess is the way it should be done in safe code.

I wonder if there's a cleaner way to the unsafe version, which, FWIW, is faster since it needn't sort the slices. (Cleaner as in without transmuting pointers or otherwise more succinctly)

Comment: @YossiKreinin The unsafe version does need to sort the slices, or verify that they don't overlap in some other way. The only reason it's currently fast is because it's totally unsound for arbitrary `slice_pairs`.

Comment: @YossiKreinin I've now added my code as an answer because the separate implementation of `split_many()` might be useful to future visitors.